# When I update version in play console it shows me this "You need to publish the artifact to any track before sharing it." instead of link

Tags: android, google-play-console, artifact, google-play-internal-testing

I already published app for testing in Internal Testing Section (Version 1) but when I upload another Version it is showing me this line and not showing link of the app anywhere . That's why I am unable to test another version of app . I am pasting the screenshot for better understanding. Thank you [Link of the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOvXO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish this version to internal testing to get link.

For that create a new release in internal testing track and add your App bundle from bundle library.

After that you will get your sharable link

Comment: Create new Release is not showing after version 1 it now showing Edit release and when i upload new version in Edit release it is showing same line again

Comment: Is there any draft in the internal release which is left to publish?